# How to specify startup file in VSCode Python Extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio's `Python Tools for Visual Studio` [(url)](https://microsoft.github.io/PTVS/) when you have a Python project file there's this notion of a [Startup File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#add-files-assign-a-startup-file-and-set-environments).

> Each Python project has one assigned start-up file, shown in boldface
>   in Solution Explorer. The startup file is the file that's run when you
>   start debugging (F5 or Debug > Start Debugging) or when you run your
>   project in the Interactive window (Shift+Alt+F5 or Debug > Execute
>   Project in Python Interactive). To change it, right-click the new file
>   and select Set as Startup File.
>   [image: Solution Explorer showing Startup File]

What's the equivalent in `VSCode`'s Python Extension? How to I target a specific file in my directory to run with the current debug settings selected from my `launch.json` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it's the `program` attribute.

> program - executable or file to run when launching the debugger
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes

As an example...

```
{
    "name": "python launch foo",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/d1/d2/foo.py",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "args": [ "${env:USERNAME}", "--optionX", "x1000" ]
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

Previously I was just duplicating launch configs with the default `file` variable which would always just run whatever active file was open in the workspace.

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
}
```